# Como parar uma Thread por determinado tempo, sem usar um Timer?

Tags: delphi, thread, multithreading, delphi-xe3, timer

## Explicação:

Seguinte, eu tenho uma `TThread` executando paralela à `Main Thread`. E tenho uma rotina pra dar um *fade* na imagem. Bom, o importante é que eu realizo esse *fade* em um determinado tempo em milissegundos, então eu fiz a rotina baseada em um `TTimer`.

## Problema:

Quando eu executo o comando do *fade*, por causa do *timer* a minha *thread* segue a execução independente do *fade* ter ou não encerrado. Porém, o que me impede de dar dois ou mais *fades* sequenciais.

Então o que eu preciso é de uma maneira de deixar a *thread* aguardando meu comando terminar.

Eu pensei em usar um *loop* simples para executar o *fade*, mas como eu poderia medir o tempo sem o *timer*? Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: @PauloRoberto por que puseste as palavras como código?

Comment: Porque relacionam à ações que envolvem código, são termos em inglês utilizados para determinado feito, pedem destaque. Objetivo é facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Termos em inglês devem ser redigidos em itálico. Não em código.

Comment: Porque deveriam? Itálico não implicaria praticamente nenhuma diferença do resto do texto. - Porém comentários como estes redigidos por mim e por você não estão ajudando no entendimento da pergunta, devem ser posteriormente excluídos.

Comment: @PauloRoberto ao meu ver, as palavras fade deveriam ser trocadas por efeito de aparecer/desaparecer/esmaecimento. Não estão relacionadas ao código de forma alguma.

Comment: Qual o problema de você criar a thread ou iniciar sua execução **só** depois do efeito acabar?

Comment: Acho que me expliquei mal. O efeito é chamado no meio da thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `GetTickCount` que te retorna um número cardinal contendo o tempo em milissegundos desde que o sistema está ligado. Depois, quando chamar de novo, é só checar a diferença.

## Dois pontos importantes:

1 - Quando o sistema fica ligado por 49,7 dias, o cardinal reinicia.

2 - Quando o computador hiberna, o valor também fica armazenado.

**Então é só você implementar uma função:**

```delphi
function VerificarTimeOut(const TickCountInicial, TempoEsperado: Cardinal): Boolean
var
  TickCountAtual: Cardinal;
begin
  TickCountAtual := GetTickCount;
  if TickCountInicial <= TickCountAtual then
    Result := (TickCountAtual - TickCountInicial) >= TempoEsperado
  else
    Result := ((MAXCARDINAL - TickCountInicial) + TickCountAtual) >= TempoEsperado;
end;
```

**Depois na thread você faz:**

```
procedure EsperaAte(const TempoEspera: Cardinal);
var
  TickCountParada: Cardinal;
begin
  TickCountParada := GetTickCount;
  while not VerificarTimeOut(TickCountParada, TempoEspera) do
    Sleep(10);
end;
```

**Obs:** Não coloque um sleep muito grande pois, se a thread receber um sinal de parada ou término ela não vai responder se estiver em sleep